# Why Spring @Qualifier does not work with Spock and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, spock

I'm trying to write a test for controller in the Spock.

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class,
    classes = [Application.class, CreateUserControllerTest.class])
@WebAppConfiguration
@Configuration
class CreateUserControllerTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ble")
    PasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context

    @Autowired
    CreateUserController testedInstance

    def "Injection works"() {
        expect:
        testedInstance instanceof CreateUserController
        userRepository != null
    }

    @Bean
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        return Mock(UserRepository.class)
    }

    @Bean(name = "ble")
    PasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor() {
        return Mock(PasswordEncryptor)
    }

}
```

Application class is just Spring Boot simplest config (enables autoscanning).It provides a with PasswordEncryptor. I want to replace this bean from Application with my bean providing a mock.

But unfortunately Spring throws a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.jasypt.util.password.PasswordEncryptor] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: provide,ble
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 54 more
```

@Qualifier annotation seems not working at all. What can I do?

***Edit***

The problem is not in the `CreateUserControllerTest` but in the `CreateUserController`.

```
public class CreateUserController {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncryptor encryptor;
}
```

There is no `@Qualifier` annotation, so Spring doesn't know which bean should inject. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make Spring to replace `PasswordEncryptor` bean from Application by local Configuration.

Comment: I strongly suggest using constructor injection instead. This lets you easily control what gets injected into the class under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Qualifier` is to wire a particular instance of bean, if you have multiple implementations of the same interface.

but still you need a 'UNIQUE' name for each bean in spring context.

So you are trying to register two beans with name '`passwordEncryptor`'. One in your test, and it seems the other one is in your actual code '`Application.class`'.

If you want to mock the 'PasswordEncryptor', either use `@Mock` or `@Spy`. (or) If you want to avoid the error, then change the name of the method to avoid the instance name collision.

```
@Mock
private PasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor;

or

@Spy
private PasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor;
```

***Edit***

Another possibility of that error is somewhere in your code you defined an `@Autowired` for '`passwordEncryptor`' without a `@Qualifier` tag,

but

you have two instances of `@Bean(name="...") passwordEncryptor` defined, so Spring context is confused to select which one to 'Auto Wire' the field.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something `expected single matching bean but found 2: provide,ble` implies that the beans have distinct names.

Comment: Thanks morfic. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I see that there is problem not with autowiring fields in the test, but in the tested instance. `CreateUserController` has internally `@Autowired` annotation to the `passwordEncryptor` but without a qualifier, so there is an conflict. Unfortunately I can't use `@Mock` annotation, because I want to use Spock's mocking framework (which doesn't provide mock injection).